# Calculating $ \| \mathbf{h} \|^{2} $ and $ \| \mathbf{h} \|^{4} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors, normed-spaces

I have a vector $ \mathbf{h} $ of size $ 1 \times M $, where each component is a complex number. How do I calculate $ \| \mathbf{h} \|^{2} $ and $ \| \mathbf{h} \|^{4} $?

For example, I use Matlab to generate $ \mathbf{h} $ such that

```
M=10;
h=randn(1,M)+1i*randn(1,M);
```

Can someone help me to calculate $ \| \mathbf{h} \|^{2} $ and $ \| \mathbf{h} \|^{4} $?

Added:
I tried following after Ross's answer:

```
h2=h*h'
h4=h2^2
```

Hope these give solutions?

```
M=3;
h=(randn(1,M)+1i*randn(1,M))
ht=h'
h2=h*ht
h4=h2^2
h =
   0.4889 - 0.3034i   1.0347 + 0.2939i   0.7269 - 0.7873i
ht =
   0.4889 + 0.3034i
   1.0347 - 0.2939i
   0.7269 + 0.7873i
h2 =
    2.6362
h4 =
    6.9497
```

Comment: Hi Frey. I see that you tried to add some more information. Please modify my edit.

Comment: No problem @Berrick, I just tried to add more info.

Comment: For $h2$ you need to sum over the components of h. Maybe that is what you get with the asterisk, but I don't know Matlab. I presume the prime is complex conjugate.

Comment: It gave me right answer Thanks @Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $||{\bf h}||^2$ you sum the absolute squares of the components, where you multiply each by its complex conjugate.  For $||{\bf h}||^4$ you just use $(||{\bf h}||^2)^2$

Comment: Thanks @Ross !!! Is this the code? h2=h*h' and
h4=h2^2

Comment: If this is a vector of complex components shouldn't you transpose and conjugate?

Comment: That's not correct for complex vectors

Comment: @Aweygan:  I missed the components were complex.  Fixed.  Thanks.